# Python: nested lists, extend & delete elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have the following list of lists:

```
list=[
['a', 1, 5],
['b', 10, 25],
['c', 2, 7],
['d', 3, 4],
['e', 0, 0]
               ]
```

which I want to process in order to end up like this:

```
list=[
['a', 1, 5],
[['b', 10, 25],['c', 2, 7]],
[['d', 3, 4], ['e', 0, 0]]
               ]
```

This means, the new list[1] should be list[1] extended by list[2] (and new list[2] should be list[3] extended by list[4]) while, at the same time, old list[2] and old list[4] are deleted from the nested list. Then, the result must be converted to pandas dataframe (for other uses) with the proper indexation. I have read about the extend() command but it seems to create another column for each of the variables inside the list. How can the result I need?

EDIT:
The wanted dataframe should be

```
     0
0 ['a', 1, 5]
1 ['b', 10, 25],['c', 2, 7]
2 ['d', 3, 4], ['e', 0, 0]
```

Comment: What's the dataframe you want in the end?

Comment: what kind of DF are you going to get from the second list???

Comment: show your resulting pandas array. I doubt, that your structure can converted to pandas.

Comment: Choosing a different variable name would be nice, and please indicate if really entry 0 shall be left as is? Do you have your current status of converting code into a panda dataframe? Extend and append are descibed in python documentation with samples. maybe take a look there and then update the question?

Comment: Neither of the lists you posted will result in the desired `dataframe`

Comment: why do you want to do that? what is your goal?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot store two separate lists in one cell. It should be a list of lists, a Series of lists or something that will contain those two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the pandas part, but for converting your first nested Python list into the second nested Python list, just do:

```
list = [list[0], [list[1], list[2]], [list[3], list[4]]]
```

This assigns a newly created nested list to `list` instead of manipulating the original list stored by `list`. The innermost lists will be the original ones, though.

Note that indexes in Python are 0-based, not 1-based.

If you want to manipulate the original nested list (e.g., because you have other references to it that must point to the changed list), do:

```
list[:] = [list[0], [list[1], list[2]], [list[3], list[4]]]
```

Comment: I will accept your answer das_g since I have come to aggree with Joe R that my wanted result can not be converted to a proper dataframe. Thank you.